# Filtrar informacion de un Datatable con instruccion IN

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

tengo la siguiente filtrado:

`dtBahias = dtBahiasCompletas.AsEnumerable() .Where(row => row.Field<String>("BAHIA") != "A1") .OrderBy(row => row.Field<String>("BAHIA")) .CopyToDataTable();`

Pero ahora quisiera que en lugar de un solo valor (A1) fueran varios valores (A1,A2,A3), así como en SQL Server utilizar la instrucción IN , pero no se si acá se podrá utilizar igual o parecido , para que pueda aceptar ese filtrado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar .Contains() para lograr chequear multiples valores:

```
valores = new string[] {"A1", "A2", "A3"};
dtBahias = dtBahiasCompletas.AsEnumerable() .Where(row => valores.Contains(row.Field<String>("BAHIA")) .OrderBy(row => row.Field<String>("BAHIA")) .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: y si quisiera que fuese NOT IN , asi como en la consulta que puse  el  !=

Comment: En ese caso usa `!valores.Contains(row.Field<String>("BAHIA"))`

Comment: Excelente , funciono de maravilla , te agradezco tu apoyo !

Comment: Genial, si te pareció util y resuelve tu problema recuerda que puedes marcar las respuestas utiles para indicar que ya fue resuelta. Si te quedan más dudas comenta lo que quieras aclarar.